# Cant retrieve the data from the Array by using method(passing) index as argument

Tags: javascript, typescript

Can't get the Array item by using method() while passing index as argument 
it shows as undefined

```
export class DataService {
    public list = [
        { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
        { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
        { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
        { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
        { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
        { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
        { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
        { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
        { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
        { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
    ]
    getList() {
        return this.list;
    }


    update(num, updated) {
        let list = this.getList()
        console.log(typeof (num))
        console.log(this.list[num])
    }
```

Comment: you need to add the 'Typescript' tag. You may get more help

Comment: thanks  changed the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array contains objects, but you want to search by `id` which is a property of those objects. You have to use `filter`:

```
console.log(this.list.find(el => el.id === id))
```

Comment: i want this.list[index] ;
example:this.list[2];
which u should give the values of 2nd indices of array

Comment: @madhavsaibhushan That works - where's the problem?